# C fork program explanation

Tags: c, fork, stdio

I have a code as below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("a\n");
    fork();

    printf("b\n");
    if(fork() == 0) {
        printf("c\n");
        exit(0);    
    }
    printf("d\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
a
b
d
a
b
c
a
b
d
a
b
c
```

I don't know why the output duplicated many times.

Comment: Are you redirecting the output to file?

Comment: You are calling `fork` twice, and the first time you don't even care about its result (but you should, and you need to handle its failure)

Comment: Use [getpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) in your `printf`, e.g. `printf("a from pid %d\n", (int)getpid());`

Comment: How and where you're running this program **is important**. Also the you should state the **expected output** too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I don't know why the output duplicated many times

Because `printf()` is buffered.

When a process calls `fork()`, the resulting child process obtains a copy of the parent's output buffer.

You can  empty this output buffer by placing `fflush(stdout)` just before each call to `fork()`. In that case output should be:

```
a
b
b
d
c
d
c
```

---

Note that if the output refered to a terminal, it would be *line-buffered* by default, i.e.: the buffer would be dumped every time a `\n` is sent to the output. Not so if you are redirecting the output to a file.

Comment: Wrong. The buffering explains the order, but not the number of outputs.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the buffering explains why `a` is being displayed more than once and why `b` is displayed four times instead of twice.

Comment: "the buffer is dumped every time a \n is sent to the output" --- if it's flushed after every `\n` why there are 4 `a`s there?

Comment: No, the buffering does not explains that. The fact that `a` is printed several times is due to the behavior of `fork` (not of `printf`).

Comment: @zerkms I am saying that the buffer is dumped if it is *line-buffered*

Comment: @zerkms I meant: if the output refers to a terminal, then it is *line-buffered* **by default**: that default behavior can be changed.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't understand what you mean. Could you please explain further?

Comment: Read [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/). An entire book is needed to explain `fork`. Replacing `printf` by `write` won't change the number of lines with `a`, it could (but practically won't) change the order of the outputs.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch replacing `printf` by `write` will display the line with `a` only once, since `write` has no user-space buffering.

Comment: But *stdout* is flushed at `exit` time, or when `main` returns. That happens in [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch but that happens after the process forked.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch he's correct here. The output is fully buffered for some reason there, probably because it is piped or this is run in some bad IDE.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `fork()` it gets a copy of output buffer of the calling process. Buffering is enabled by default, so you get this behavior. 
You can use

```
fflush(stdout);
```

before a call to fork(). Or, you can also disable buffering using

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

You can read more about fork [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html). Let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already in the comments. You are calling `fork()` twice. So the solution is to just call it once and save the result in a variable like this `int pid = fork()`. Also, you should check if the fork-call failed (if it does, it returns a negative value).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("a\n");

    int pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't fork!");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("b\n");

    if(pid == 0)
    {
        printf("c\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("d\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```